# Firefox Addon Using preferences as RightClick Submenu

Tags: firefox, split, firefox-addon, menuitem, preferences

I´m currently developing an Add-On for Firefox and I have two preferences where as in the first, the user can enter IDs  comma seperated. (I.e.: 29, 39, 110).
In the second preference goes the associated name for the ID. i.e. Name for ID 29, Name for ID 39, Name for 110.

In my ff-overlay.xul I have:

```
 <menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
     <menu id="addto" label="Add Video to ">
        <menupopup>
          <menuitem label="NAME" oncommand="insert(ID)" />
        </menupopup>   
     </menu> 
 </menupopup>
```

I want a menuitem for every ID there is,
display the name and pass the ID as a parameter to my function.

Is this possible to do? Thank you in advance

Comment: can you change to have just one preference and make it hold json? like `{vidId1:vidName1,vidIdN:vidNameN}` that would be nicer

Comment: Sure I could make that too, but it still holds up the question how I would go about putting it in a submenu. with json?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the menu on runtime see this snippet here:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9523055

Some explanation on how I made that script, and some simplifications are seen in the topic here: [can I add a context menu to a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300814/can-i-add-a-context-menu-to-a-widget)

Comment: Thank´s. I will check it out tonight. Do you have an addon that uses this code?

Comment: You can copy paste that code into scratchpad, change widget id to whatever id and it will work